# Como listar e consultar contatos com PHP e Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, aplicação-web

Olá, preciso de um exemplo bem prático em PHP que me traga a **lista de contatos** de uma tabela do banco de dados, e que ao **clicar** em um contato seja exibida as **informações** do mesmo. Acompanhe a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante em PHP, já tentei utilizar a consulta por AJAX, mas não obtive sucesso. Tentei pesquisar em inúmeros locais algum exemplo que pudesse me ajudar com a questão, mas não encontrei nada também.

Gostaria de realizar isso sem atualizar a tela ou redirecionar para outra página (Javascript).

Conto com a ajuda de vocês, obrigado!

Comment: Tente quebrar seu problema em problemas menores do jeito que esta fica muito amplo e difícil de alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Você está pedindo um exemplo enquanto deveria postar uma dúvida. Me desculpe mas a questão do jeito que está não se adequa aos modelos do site. Sugiro fazer um [tour] e ler o guia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta assim ARQUIVO HTML

```
<html>
<title>teste</title>
<head>
    <!-- CSS aqui -->
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Consultar</h1>

    <p>Clique no botao</p>
    <p><button class='doQuery' data-userid='1'>Marco</button></p>
    <p><button class='doQuery' data-userid='2'>Alvori</button></p>
    <p><button class='doQuery' data-userid='3'>Cintia</button></p>
    <p><button class='doQuery' data-userid='4'>Jair</button></p>

    <hr>
    <div id='resultadofinal'></div>

<!-- JS aqui no final da pagina para carregar mais rapido -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    $.system = {};
    $.system.path = '/stackoverflow/exemplo1/'; // ou colocar a pasta raiz $.system.path = '/';

    jQuery(".doQuery").click(function(){

        var id_usuario = $(this).attr('data-userid');

        jQuery.post( $.system.path + 'result.php' , { id_usuario:id_usuario,outraval:'valor_da_val' } , function(result,status){ 


            if( status == 'success' )
            {

                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

                if( json.resultStatus == 'success' )
                {

                    jQuery("#resultadofinal").html(json.html);

                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery("#resultadofinal").html(json.resultMSG);

                }

            } 
            else
            {
                alert('Erro no requisicao jquery');
            }


        } );
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ARQUIVO result.php - fazer a sua sql conforme o seu banco aqui peguei exemplo do xampp

```
<?php 

$con   = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db    = mysql_select_db('webauth',$con);


if( isset($_POST['id_usuario'])){

    // input    
    $id    = $_POST['id_usuario'];

    ####
    $html  = array();
    $table = 'user_pwd';

    // your SQL


    //Query
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE id = '{$id}'",$con);

    if( mysql_error() )
    {
        $html['resultStatus'] = 'error';    
        $html['resultMSG']    = mysql_error();
    } 
    else
    {

        if( mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1 )
        {

            $html['resultStatus'] = 'success';      

            $html['html'] = "
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nome</td>
                    <td>Senha</td>
                </tr>
            ";

            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) )
            {

                //aqui voce define os dados da sua table
                $html['html'] .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['pass']}</td>
                    </tr>

                ";

            }

            $html['html'] .= "</table>";

        } 
        else
        {
            $html['resultStatus'] = 'error';        
            $html['resultMSG'] = 'Nenhum resultado';                    
        }

    }



    // output
    echo json_encode($html);


}
?>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @MarcosViniciusDosSantos, feito! cara só modifica o arquivo result.php coloquei na condição or TRUE, retira isso, ja fiz a edição da resposta. abs

Comment: Ah sim, já até fiz um teste aqui, está funcionando perfeitamente. Me ajudou pra caramba, muito obrigado Rafael!

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que com method get fica fácil...

cada contato daquela lista é um link que vai para a mesma página só que com uma extenção tipo essa ( estou me baseando na url que aparece na imagem):

> teste.php?contato=nome_contato

```
<?php 

// se existir o contato na url...
if(isset($_GET['contato'])){

$contato = $_GET['contato'];

//seleciona todos os dados daquele contato
$selecionaContato = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contato WHERE nomeContato='$contato'");
while($dadosContato = mysql_fetch_array(selecionaContato)){   
//mostre abaixo todos os dados do usuário selecionado
?>

 <p>Nome Completo: <?php echo $dadosContato['nome'];?></p>
 <p>telefone: <?php echo $dadosContato['tel'];?></p>
 <p>Endereço: <?php echo $dadosContato['endereco'];?></p>


  <?php }
  // fecha o while
  // se nao existir o contato na url mostra o texto abaixo..

   }else{ ?>


  <p>Selecione um contato no menu a esquerda</p>


  <?php } // fecha o else ?>
```

é bem simples esse tipo de metodo, se você precisa de uma segurança maior, recomendo o method post

se você nao criou uma slug na sua tabela aconselho vc fazer verificação pelo id de cada contato.. tipo isso...

> teste.php?idContato=1

```
$id = $_GET['idContato'];
// force para que a variavel id seja um numero para evitar hachers
$id = (int)$id;
//seleciona todos os dados daquele contato pelo id
$selecionaContato = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contato WHERE     idContato='$id'");
```

ai o resto é igual...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Andrei! Desculpa, eu acabei esquecendo de específicar. Mas, eu gostaria de estar fazendo isso sem dar refresh na tela. Ou seja, por javascript.

Mas vou guardar este seu exemplo como alternativa, caso eu não consiga fazer em JS.

Comment: Nunca, nunca, **NUNCA** construa consultas fazendo interpolação de string (i.e. `$bla` dentro da string). O que acontece se eu tiver o D'Artagnan na minha lista de contatos? (cf. [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/por-que-consultas-sql-parametrizadasnome-previnem-sql-injection))