# Column 'nome da coluna' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando montar um `left join` onde quero os resultados de determinado codigo. O meu SQL é:

```php
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT CA.DAT_EHORA_EVENT, CA.TXT_NOMEX_EVENT, CA.MEM_DESCR_EVENT FROM tbl_CLIENTES C LEFT JOIN tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA CA ON CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '".$COD_IDENT_CLIEN."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

O erro que está voltando é:

```
Column 'COD_IDENT_CLIEN' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: Isso não está diretamente relacionado a sua pergunta, mas leia [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/por-que-consultas-sql-parametrizadasnome-previnem-sql-injection).

Comment: @ctgPi Obrigado pela dica, irei averiguar com certeza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este erro é bem simples, a coluna COD_IDENT_CLIEN exite em ambas as tabelas e por isso precisa ser especificada na cláusula WHERE, logo, coloque

`WHERE CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = ...`

ou

`WHERE C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = ...`

Comment: Obrigado deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 3):

O que acontece é que você tem duas colunas chamadas `COD_IDENT_CLIEN` (uma na tabela `tbl_CLIENTES` e a outra na tabela `tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA`) e o MySQL não tem como saber a qual das duas você está se referindo no seu `WHERE`:

```sql
WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN
```

Uma vez que você está especificando `CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN` então tanto faz qual seria a coluna escolhida, pois as duas são iguais. Assim, você pode corrigir isso usando qualquer uma delas:

```sql
WHERE C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN
```

E o seu código fica assim:

```php
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT CA.DAT_EHORA_EVENT, CA.TXT_NOMEX_EVENT, CA.MEM_DESCR_EVENT FROM tbl_CLIENTES C LEFT JOIN tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA CA ON CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN WHERE C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '".$COD_IDENT_CLIEN."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

E por sinal, cuidado com a [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). O seu código está sofrendo com este problema. Use os [*prepared statements*](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/evite-sql-injection-usando-prepared-statements-no-php) do PHP para resolver este problema.

Comment: Como posso mudar para resolver isto ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Editei a resposta para mostrar como resolver isto.

Comment: Falo em relação ao injeção de sql ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Sobre sql injection pode começar com, [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91), [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?] 
(http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91) e por último [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91).

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você tem duas colunas chamadas `COD_IDENT_CLIEN`: `C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN` e `CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN`.

Eu sei que você especificou `CA.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN`, então é lógico que quando você se refere a `COD_IDENT_CLIEN`, qualquer uma das duas colunas serve, mas infelizmente o padrão do SQL não permite que o SGBD faça essa inferência.

Em alguns SGBDs, você poderia escrever

```
FROM tbl_CLIENTES C NATURAL LEFT JOIN tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA CA
```

e aí não só o JOIN seria feito automaticamente, igualando todas as colunas com nomes iguais nas duas tabelas, como, conceitualmente, o resultado teria apenas uma coluna chamada `COD_IDENT_CLIEN`, e aí o seu `WHERE` funcionaria do jeito que você espera.

(Infelizmente, o MySQL não é um desses sistemas — já cogitou a possibilidade de migrar para o PostgreSQL?)

Comment: Bacana, não, na verdade nunca pensei em migrar para o PostgreSQL, mais irei estudar mais sobre o mesmo.