# Capturar Mês em campo date

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo `date` no meu banco de dados MySQL e ele armazena as data do tipo `y-m-d` que já é usado em outras consultas, mas agora preciso capturar somente o mês para realizar uma soma.

O código que eu tenho é esse

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $datamensal = date('m-d');
        $stw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(valortotal) as total_mensal FROM pedidos WHERE data = '$datamensal'");
```

Mas não funcionou....
Alguém sabe a forma correta de realizar está ação?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [month()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) do MySQL para fazer a comparação apenas do mês com o valor desejado. Existem outras funções para extrair um pedaço da data como `year()`, `day()` etc.

```
select month(now()) #retorna 11
```

ou

```
$datamensal = date('m');
$stw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(valortotal) as total_mensal FROM pedidos 
                    WHERE month(data) = '$datamensal' AND year(data) = year(now())")
       or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stw)){
   echo $row['total_mensal'] .'<br>';
}
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/91)

Comment: Mas ai tipo, nesse caso ele retorna igual a 11 qual função eu uso pra capturar a data atual do meu computador e fazer a comparação.

Comment: @AlfredoLima você já está usando o `date()` do php, é so pedir o mês para ele. no lugar de `m-d`

Comment: Ah tá, entendi, verifica pra mim se está correto..
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $datamensal = date('m');
        $stw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(valortotal) as total_mensal FROM pedidos 
                    WHERE month(data) = '$datamensal'");

Comment: É para ser isso @AlfredoLima, vai somar todos os registros do mês de novembro, é bom especificar o ano tbm ;), você não quer somar os registros dos anos anteriores. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: eu fiz da forma que você falou, mas não funcionou, ele não exibe nada.

Comment: @AlfredoLima, com o year() parou de funcionar ou já estava certo? apareceu algum erro?

Comment: Não ele já não estava funcionando, nenhum erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31122/discussion-between-rray-and-alfredo-lima).

Comment: @AlfredoLima se resolveu não esqueça de aceitar a resposta :)