# Como converter uma string de uma planilha para formato de data para o mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-excel

Estou pegando uma planilha o excel em formato date porém no banco de dados insere como string no formato text no excel apesar de esta em date

tente converter pelo mysql porém no insert aparece o seguinte erro column

> 'nome da coluna' cannot be null

segue o insert

```
$salesplan_insert = mysqli_query($link,"insert into prom.absenteismo(`matricula` , `funcionario` , `lider` , `linha` , `falta`, `data_falta`, `observacao`) values ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e', date_format('$f', '%Y-%m-%d'),'$g')");
```

já usei também o `STR_TO_DATE()` também não funcionou alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o conteúdo das variaveis que estão sendo usadas na consulta?
Tenha cuidado também, pois a sua consulta está vulnerável a [injeção de sql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/por-que-consultas-sql-parametrizadasnome-previnem-sql-injection)

Comment: a variavel $f aparece 42803 porém na planilha esta em data 9/9/2017

Comment: @claudomarso o Excel trabalha com números que são transformados em data para a visualização do usuário. Seria necessário ou converter tudo em texto e então seu _insert_ estaria correto ou será necessário tratar essa data para que seja extraída no formato data de fato e não o código *42803* que o Excel entende como data. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: eu tentei em php dessa forma date('Y/m/d', strtotime($f)); porém vem com uma data de 1969