# Erro ao gravar novo registro no banco de dados Access

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, crud

Estou fazendo um *CRUD* com *Winforms* no *C#*, estou com um erro ao inserir a data no campo data de nascimento. Esta apresentado a seguinte mensagem ao tentar gravar o novo registro:

> Erro de sintaxe operador faltado na expressão de consulta '10/02/1986 00:00'

Segue abaixo trecho do código

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Cliente (descCliente, nomefantasia, endereco, complemento, bairro, cep, estado, cidade, "
                + "telefone1, telefone2, celular1, email, CPF, RG, OEmissor, DtNasc)"
                //, CPF, RG, OEmissor, bloqueado, mensalista) "
                + "VALUES ('" + txtnome.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtFantasia.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtRua.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtComplemento.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtBairro.Text + "', "
                + "'" + mskCEP.Text + "', "
                + Convert.ToInt32(txtEstado.Text) + ", "
                + Convert.ToInt32(txtCidade.Text) + ","
                + "'" + mskFone1.Text + "', "
                + "'" + mskfone2.Text + "', "
                + "'" + mskcelular.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtemail.Text + "', "
                + "'" + mskCPF.Text + "', "
                + "'" + mskRG.Text + "', "
                + "'" + txtEmissor.Text + "', "
                +  Convert.ToDateTime(mskDOB.Text) + "); ";    
                //+ false + ", "
                //+ false + ");";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql , conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i>0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("inclusão efetuada com sucesso");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Abaixo a *String SQL*

> "INSERT INTO Cliente (descCliente, nomefantasia, endereco, complemento, bairro, cep, estado, cidade, telefone1, telefone2, celular1, email, CPF, RG, OEmissor, DtNasc)VALUES ('fernando', 'fer', 'rua 1', '', 'limoeiro', '00125-455', 2, 1960,'(11) 1111-1111', '(  )     -', '(11) 91111-1111', 'me@me.com', '   .   .   -', '111.111.111-11', 'SSP-PS', 10/02/1986 00:00:00); "

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: talvez seja as aspas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te aconselho a não usar dessa forma...Você está concatenando os valores dentro da query. Tente imputar os valores usando parâmetros. Isto evitará problemas que possam a vir futuramente tipo [injeção de código](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e não te dará esses problemas com data. O código ficaria assim:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Cliente (descCliente, nomefantasia, endereco, 
complemento, bairro, cep, estado, cidade, "
                + "telefone1, telefone2, celular1, email, CPF, RG, OEmissor, 
DtNasc)"
            //, CPF, RG, OEmissor, bloqueado, mensalista) "
            + "VALUES (@descCliente, @nomefantasia, @endereco, @complemento, @bairro, @cep, @estado, @cidade, "
            + "@telefone1, @telefone2, @celular1, @email, @CPF, @RG, @OEmissor, @DtNasc) ";
        //+ false + ", "
        //+ false + ");";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
           {
               new OleDbParameter("@descCliente",  txtnome.Text),
               new OleDbParameter("@nomefantasia", txtFantasia.Text),
               ...
           });

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inclusão efetuada com sucesso");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Dica**: Talvez seja importante você começar a trabalhar com parâmetros nas *queries*. Da forma atual é muito fácil que algum invasor consiga fazer um *SQL injection* (leia sobre isso, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/18246) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/18246)) no seu código.

Você precisa inserir a data no formato **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** e circundada por *hash*/jogo da velha/*sharp*/sustenido (**`#`**) **ou aspas simples**.

Ou seja, o *insert* deveria ficar assim

```
INSERT INTO Cliente (descCliente, nomefantasia, endereco, complemento, bairro, cep, estado, 
                  cidade, telefone1, telefone2, celular1, email, CPF, RG, OEmissor, DtNasc)
VALUES ('fernando', 'fer', 'rua 1', '', 'limoeiro', '00125-455', 2, 1960,
        '(11) 1111-1111', '( ) -', '(11) 91111-1111', 'me@me.com', ' . . -', 
        '111.111.111-11', 'SSP-PS', #1986-02-10 00:00:00#);
```

Ou (só o final pra não ficar repetindo tudo)

```
'1986-02-10 00:00:00'
```

Pra formatar a data é só usar `.ToString()`.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(mskDOB.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```