# como inserir um comando de select no BD usando c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

Eu queria ter uma tabela de comandos de select no banco, e que fossem lidas em uma combobox. Tenho uma textbox onde escrevo o comando a ser executado pelo banco, um botão para o mesmo e uma combobox com comandos gravados. Quando o comando que quero executar não está na combobox, eu digito. E queria que fosse gravado para ser lida na combobox se esse não existisse.
Fiz assim:

```
public OracleDataReader VerificarComandoExistente(string descricao)
        {
         strQuery = "select * from comando where comando = '" + descricao + "' ";
            return ObjBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
        }
```

No C# não aceita dessa forma, quando coloco um comando com where onde tem que ter as aspas. Ex select * from all_tables where owner ='hr' . Não lê o hr.

No banco fiz o teste, trocando '' por "". Rodou normal no sqldeveloper, mas não no c#.

Resumindo. O sistema tem que receber o código, verificar no banco se existe, e gravar na tabela se não existe.

> Olha eu entendi o que está acontecendo. Eu faço um select simples e o resultado vai para o datagridview:
>
> " select * from all_tables where owner = 'HR' "
>
> Depois de ter feito isso se este comando não está no banco, ele vai precisar ser gravado. Daí um select diferente:
>
> " select comando from comando where comando ='select * from all_tables where owner ='HR' ' "
>
> O segundo select roda após ao primeiro
>
> O problema  é que as aspas simples funciona no primeiro comando e no segundo comando tem que ser aspas dupla para o Oracle reconhecer (funciona direto no Oracle)
>   Teria que ser algo igual ao método Replace, só que acho que não troca aspas...
>
> Nenhuma das soluções deu certo

Answer (score 4):

Poderia tentar dar uma resposta que apenas resolve seu problema, mas já fizeram isso na outra resposta. Ao invés disso vou te passar como você deveria estar fazendo.

Seu código é inseguro, não faça seus comandos de banco de dados dessa forma em hipótese alguma. Eles serão extremamente **vulneráveis**.

Você não informou qual o adaptador está usando para conectar com o banco então começarei dando um exemplo com o [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/18.3.0) que é o mais aconselhável para o `Oracle` na minha opinião, mas que também pode ser usado com o [`Oracle.DataAccess.Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/connecting.htm#TDPNG30000):

```
strQuery = "select * from comando where comando = :MeuParametro";
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, db);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MeuParametro", varParametro));
```

Essa é a forma correta de você passar parâmetros para sua string. Considere alterar seu código.

Além de evitar o seu problema original de precisar passar ou não com aspas, você terá um código seguro.

**Segue abaixo um exemplo de um método completo:**

```
public MeuComando VerificarComandoExistente(string comando)
{
    //Esse é apenas um objeto de exemplo que uso pra retornar os dados
    MeuComando objMeuComando = new MeuComando();

    string connectionString = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=user;Password=pwd;";
    string sql = @"select * from comando where comando = :MeuComando";
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":MeuComando", comando);
        OracleDataReader oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Utiliza aqui o if caso seja apenas uma linha de retorno...
        while (oraReader.Read())
        {
            objMeuComando = new MeuComando
            {//Aqui é onde vai preecher os dados retornados do BD para retornar no seu método.
                coluna1 = oraReader.GetInt32(0),
                coluna2 = oraReader.GetString(1),
                coluna3 = oraReader.GetString(2)
            };
        }
        return objMeuComando;
    }
}
```

E caso queira entender melhor sobre esse assunto separei questões aqui mesmo do **SOpt** sobre esse assunto:

1. [Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/por-que-consultas-sql-parametrizadasnome-previnem-sql-injection)
2. [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection)

Comment: como eu faria o código completo, eu não sei porque fui ensinado da forma errada. Adaptador = Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, é exatamente da forma que coloquei na resposta, mas pra facilitar coloquei um método completo como exemplo e melhorei alguns pontos da resposta pra você tentar corrigir seu código.

Comment: desculpa mas não entendi o 'db' acima, não está declarado...

Comment: @MarcusVinicius, no primeiro exemplo eu coloquei apenas um trecho. O 'db' é um objeto OracleConnection que no segundo exemplo está com o nome "conn".

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da versão do C# que está usando você pode usar assim

```
public OracleDataReader VerificarComandoExistente(string descricao)
    {
     strQuery = $"select * from comando where comando = {descricao}";
        return ObjBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
    }
```

Pode-se usar assim também

```
  public OracleDataReader VerificarComandoExistente(string descricao)
    {
     strQuery = string.format("select * from comando where comando = {0}",descricao);
        return ObjBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho a resposta do George Wurthmann a mais correta, porém, caso queira apenas saber a sintaxe, já tentou retirar as " e ' da concatenação? Em c# você pode apenas chamar a variável no final de uma string.

**Ex: strQuery = "... comando = " + descricao;**

```
  public OracleDataReader VerificarComandoExistente(string descricao) {
          strQuery = "select * from comando where comando = " + descricao;
             return ObjBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
         }
```